# Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments' (prefer-rest-params)

Tags: ecmascript-6

I can not solve this case - linter points me to other solution. This is my original code:

```
if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === 'object') {
  this.options = extendDefaultProperties(defaultProperties, arguments[0]);
}
```

Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about reading the documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-rest-params

Comment: Do you know what rest parameters are?

Comment: @FelixKling But it's not always as easy as rewriting your function's parameters. What if you wanted to `console.log([].slice.call(arguments).filter(x => x).join())` within a function where you wanted to have explicit (non-rest) parameters in the signature? That is, even if the code in this question doesn't seem to preclude having rest params in its function definition, there could be reasons you'd want to iterate arguments easily, even if just for debugging, right? Then what? ;^) (Though I think the answer is `// eslint-disable-next-line`, unfortunately. Wish there was a dictionary of them.)

Comment: @ruffin: Yes, but if it's just for debugging (i.e. temporary), then I woudn't care about linter rules anyway. If it's supposed to be permanent I can think of two solutions: Either use a rest parameter and create local variables via `let [arg1, arg2, ....] == allParameters;`, or vice versa, use normal arguments and create an array out of them. Both of these are of course less convenient, but I'd argue if people want convenience they wouldn't use a linter :D (jk)

Answer (score 24):

Use the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to collect the params into the array `args`:

```
demo(...args) {
  if (typeof args[0] === 'object' && args[0] !== null) {
    this.options = extendDefaultProperties(defaultProperties, args[0]);
  }
}
```